# How to deploy angular app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Please, give me the step by step procedure to deploy the Angular app from visual studio code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have created the AWS EB with Nodejs environment.

I made a build of the angular code, made a zip file and deployed to the AWS EB.  When deployed it creates error in the events and made the environment degraded.

Here is the error I got from AWS EB
https://i.stack.imgur.com/okTIL.jpg

Comment: Are you sure it's an AngularJS app, not Angular 2+? Please share a [mcve] of your code.